# height 100% custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

Is there any library / plugin for a custom scrollbar which supports the height 100% property or just percentage at all? I've tested like dozens of jQuery scrollbar plugins but none of them seem to work properly without fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var objHeight = window.innerHeight;// to get the pixel height
```

and set the pixel height of the plugin you are trying to use to

```
(objHeight.toString() + "px")
```

To get the innerHeight or innerWidth of other DOM elements with jQuery, try jQuery's own innerWidth/innerHeight() method: http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/  .

NOTE: If you have a border on the object, use the normal height and width() methods instead of innerHeight() or innerWidth() since the inner methods include element padding but not borders.

If you need the scrollbar to scale to height or width changes, create a callback on a jQuery resize event:

```
var resizeFn = function() {
//do resize calcs with getting height and widths and 
// setting plugin updates to new height and width
}
$(window).resize(functionName);
```

Comment: Or you could use the standard scrollbars and set the css of the element you want a scrollbar on to overflow:auto; or overflow:scroll; and then set the height to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You've tested dozen plugins, but miss some: try to use [jQuery Scrollbar](http://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar), which does not require height to be set. Also, height can be limited with standard css `max-height` value in `px` or `%` of parent container.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a [custom scrollbar library named SimpleScrollbar](https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar).

It does not depend on any other library/framework, and it's less than 1KB after gzip and minification.

It uses the native scroll, so there are no hacks, and the performance is awesome.

---

You only need to include the library in your page, and use the `ss-container` attribute in any div that you want to make scrollable. Live example:

```html
<link href="http://buzinas.github.io/simple-scrollbar/simple-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="height: 180px; width: 200px; display: inline-block;" ss-container>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<section style="height: 180px; width: 300px; display: inline-block;" ss-container>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
      <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?</p>
</section>
<!--[if IE 9]><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/classlist/2014.01.31/classList.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="http://buzinas.github.io/simple-scrollbar/simple-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
```

---

It works on all the modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge), and on IE10 and IE11. You can also use it in IE9 by including a classList polyfill.

All Android, iOS and Windows Phone browsers are supported either.

---

It supports the `height: 100%` you asked, as soon as the parent container has a height defined, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/z19w2Lfa/